# Pygame camera locks the brightness at -1

Tags: python, pygame

Iam trying to use pygame camera to take a picture from my computer cam, but for some reason it always comes out as completely black.

After some research I found out the brightness of the camera (`camera.get_controls()`) is set to -1 and can't be changed with `camera.set_controls()`

**Code:**

```
# initializing  the camera
pygame.camera.init()
  
# make the list of all available cameras
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

# if camera is detected or not
if camlist:
    # initializing the cam variable with default camera
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[3], (2952, 1944), "RGB")

    # opening the camera
    cam.start()

    # sets the brightness to 1
    cam.set_controls(True, False, 1)

    # capturing the single image
    image = cam.get_image()

    # saving the image
    pygame.image.save(image, str(cam.get_controls()) + ".png")
  
else:
    print("No camera on current device")
```

Comment: What pygame version, what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

`Pygame.camera` tries to be a non blocking API, so it can be used well in a game loop.

The problem is that you open the camera and immediately call `get_image()`. But no image has been generated yet, so it returns a fully black Surface. Maybe it should be changed on pygame’s end to be a blocking call for the first `get_image()`

On my system, it works if I put a one second delay before `get_image()`.

You can also use the `query_image()` function to return if a frame is ready.

*Asterisk: This may differ between operating systems, as it uses different backends on different systems.

Comment: On my machine I've found it takes 0.5 seconds (sometimes 0.45 seconds) before the camera is ready to return images. Calling `query_image()` will return `True` even if the camera will return an all-black Surface. Adding a manual `time.sleep(0.5)` is a simple hack workaround.